# Mysql Select on row values

Tags: mysql, sql

Im trying to create a plugin for wordpress and I encounter a table with a structure like this

[image]

Sample data

[image]

How should my MySQL `Select` query look like if I want to get

```
user_id  where City = 'CityName' and Gender = 'Male' //sample query
```

Something like

```
SELECT user_id,value,country FROM `wp_bp_xprofile_data` WHERE value = 'CityName' AND value = 'Male' GROUP BY user_id
```

OUTPUT should like

```
1 | nameofperson_1 | country_name
2 | nameofperson_2 | country_name
3 | nameofperson_3 | country_name
4 | nameofperson_4 | country_name
```

Comment: You question is a little unclear. Please provide more detail of how the output should look.

Comment: Reason of upvote ? "unclear what you are asking"

Comment: Which is which? Which are the column names and which are the rows?

Comment: wait..ill add a real data

Comment: Thanks for all the help guys..well all answers was right. but i need to choose one :)

Comment: i can give only my upvote :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to match the `field_id` with a particular value you'll have to match them in pairs `(field_id AND value)`. Then you will have to count the amount of matches.

```
SELECT user_id FROM wp_bp_xprofile_data t
WHERE (field_id = 270 AND value = 'Gender') OR
      (field_id = 354 AND value = 'City')
GROUP BY user_id
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
```

Fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/415c8d/1).

One thing that results from applying the Entity-Attribute-Value (EAV) model is that your tables are not normalized then you should make sure that you don't have more than one `field_id` for a given `user_id` with the same value.

A workaround for this would be to query:

```
HAVING COUNT(distinct field_id) = 2
```

But this won't solve the data issue, of course.

**Edit:**

Given your question update... in order to return the additional data probably putting the conditions in the `having` clause might be better:

```
SELECT
  user_id,
  max(case when field_id = 270 then value end) nameOfPerson,
  max(case when field_id = 354 then value end) cityName
FROM wp_bp_xprofile_data t
GROUP BY user_id
HAVING SUM(
  (field_id = 270 AND value = 'Gender') +
  (field_id = 354 AND value = 'City')
) = 2
```

Fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2af87/1).

Comment: what does having sum do?

Comment: It sums the amount of conditions that you want. In this case there are 2 conditions so it makes sure that both of them are matched

Answer (score 1):

Assuming wp_bp_xprofile_data is for table above, and `value` has real value rather than "Name", "Gender" etc.

could you try this?

```
SELECT t1.user_id, t1.value, t2.value
FROM wp_bp_xprofile_data t1
  INNER JOIN wp_bp_xprofile_data t2 ON t1.user_id = t2.user_id
WHERE t1.field_id = 270 AND t1.value = 'Mail'
  AND t2.field_id = 354 AND t2.value = 'CityName'
```

Answer (score 1):

Now that I see your question have a desired output, try the following:

```
SELECT t3.user_id, t3.value, t.value FROM
wp_bp_xprofile_data t 
LEFT JOIN wp_bp_xprofile_data t1 ON t1.user_id = t.user_id
LEFT JOIN wp_bp_xprofile_data t2 on t2.user_id = t.user_id
LEFT JOIN wp_bp_xprofile_data t3 on t3.user_id = t.user_id
WHERE t2.field_id = 270 AND t2.value="Male" AND
t1.field_id=354 AND t1.value="CityName" AND
t3.field_id=1 AND
t.field_id=73
```